# Laravel 4 - Class 'Stripe' not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Stripe into my project but I'm having issues. I'm getting the error

> Class 'Stripe' not found

I used

> composer require stripe/stripe-php

and everything installed fine, but I'm still having issues.

This is the line that is causing the problem:

```
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "~2.0@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libs",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"

        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

There is nothing about Stripe in my app/config/app.php file... I'm not sure if there should be a service provider for Stripe.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the API key? Have you tried `composer dump`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking [at packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php), you can see the composer package `stripe/stripe-php` point to [the following GitHub repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php).  Based on [that repository's code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe.php) and the [Stripe API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php), it doesn't look like there's a global class named `Stripe` defined.  So when you say

```
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
```

and PHP says

> Class 'Stripe' not found

PHP is telling you the truth.  There **is** a class named `Stripe\Stripe` -- so you probably want to do this

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
```

or import the class into your current PHP file with the `use` statement

```
<?php
//...
use Stripe\Stripe;
//...
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
```

Comment: Yep. It *was* `\Stripe` previously, which could be what led to the confusion. However, [v2.0 added proper namespacing](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/commit/ac931109ab94f5b1ed10be8c8cb4e7cd9ff4b00d). With that update, classes changed from `\Stripe` to `\Stripe\Stripe`, `\Stripe_Charge` to `\Stripe\Charge` etc.

Comment: @cmcg, Alan Strom did you got the answer of the following question?I am facing the same probem. if anyone can help!